# crypto currency Api help (cryptsy,mintpal,coins-e,etc)

Tags: api, converters, bitcoin, libtcod, coinbase-api

i am developing a bitcoins based site i want to convert bitcoin into alt coins and then send the altcoins automatically to the user given alt coin address, but when i try to implement it
but  i didn't find the appropriate api to implement it on my website so my question is how can i convert BTC to any altcoin via API and how can i send coins to any address using api.

I'm currently using cryptsy.com API's they also not providing any function that send coins using they api service.

**please help me to solve this issue.**

Answer (score -1):

As you are developing site for conversion between different coins and then automatically sent the converted coins to requested user, this is not how it works. you can convert Alternative coins using these API's or you can send coins by using those coins provider we deals with one type of coin for transactions/transfer between different wallet address. 
etc : https://coinbase.com/

Keep in mind there are two type of degital currency trading one is crypto Trade that provide features of conversion and second one who deals with a specific not general digital coins.

hope this help you.

Answer (score -1):

You could try using Cryptsy API (https://www.cryptsy.com/pages/api), which allows you to generate deposit addresses for any altcoin that it supports, as well as trade (buy and sell) any altcoin to BTC or LTC (or sometimes DOGE).